# Excel compare cells in columns A and B, show in column C cells only unique to column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting

I know there's a formula for this in Excel but I can't get it right.
I've got a list of 7000+ names in column A, and a list of 4000+ names in column B.  Some are duplicates, appearing on both column A and column B.
I want to filter and display the result in column C of those names that ONLY appear in column A.  If a name appears in both column A and column B, I don't want it to show in column C.
There are some close examples on here already but I can't seem to get the formulas adapted correctly to do this.
Thanks for any tips; I'm kind of lost at the moment.

Comment: Are there any duplicates within either column (e.g. can Company A appear twice in the first column, or in the second column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel can do this easily (assuming that there are no duplicates in either column).

1. Convert your data to a Table.
2. Add a helper column, with the following formula `=MATCH([ColumnA],[ColumnB],0)`. This will look up each value in your first column (A) and if it finds a match in your second column (B), it will return its relative position (helpful for finding it if you need to).  But more importantly, it returns #N/A for any values it doesn't find.
3. Filter for #N/A in Column C for values that appear in Column A, but not B.

By converting your data to a Table (Step 1), you won't need to fill down values (the Table does that) and you can automatically filter based upon the error value.

Comment: A better solution than mine +1

Answer (score 0):

You can put in column `C` this formula, but you'll have to fill it down the height of column `A`, then you'll need to re-sort it to remove blanks (probably after pasting values).

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B:$B,0)),A1,"")`

You'd be better off using advanced filters, I think.